# Trying to put the two groups in the same list box

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I have a members name coming from a database. Now I need to display these items in a list box. I have another table products coming from database.

As per client requirement, I need to display these items in the same list box.

[image: list box diagram]

Is it possible to place two lists of items in the same list box separated by empty space? And is it possible to trigger some action when clicking on an item?

Could anyone please help on this?

If it's not possible with list box, is it possible in a list view to add two groups in a single column separated with white space as shown in the figure above?

Comment: Why not use a ListView and have two columns?

Comment: is it posssible to display all items in one cloumn seperated by empty space... by using the list view

Comment: @Mamta Dalal  do u have any sample code for dividing two groups in list view and those  are displayed in single column .....

Comment: would any one pls help on this......i am searching for this around two days....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of a ListView with groups:

This MSDN article has a more advanced example: [ListViewGroup Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewgroup.aspx)

Be aware that groups are only supported on certain operating systems (XP and above I think), so you will need to factor this in to your code.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader() { Width=-1 });
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

ListViewGroup membersGroup = new ListViewGroup("Members", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Groups.Add(membersGroup);
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "Member 1", Group = membersGroup });
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "Member 2", Group = membersGroup });

ListViewGroup productsGroup = new ListViewGroup("Products", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Groups.Add(productsGroup);
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "Product 1", Group = productsGroup });
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "Product 2", Group = productsGroup });
```

And here is an example using a TreeView:

```
var members = new[] 
            {
                new { MemberName = "Member 1", MemberId = 1 },
                new { MemberName = "Member 2", MemberId = 2 }
            };
var products = new[] 
            {
                new { ProductName = "Product 1", ProductId = 1 },
                new { ProductName = "Product 2", ProductId = 2 }
            };

TreeNode membersNode = new TreeNode("Members", members.Select(m => new TreeNode(m.MemberName)).ToArray());
TreeNode productsNode = new TreeNode("Products", products.Select(p => new TreeNode(p.ProductName)).ToArray());

treeView1.Nodes.Add(membersNode);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(productsNode);
```

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like that's a task for a TreeView!

Edit:
Or check this out!

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx

or

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeWithColumns.aspx

Comment: do u know how to add items to tree view i want member names coming from database and productnames will be manually added and i have members table with memberid and membername......

Comment: thanks ... But i have to use list view with single column using different groups

Comment: i need to display members and products like this below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx but i didnot find any source code for that.. would you pls help on this one...

Comment: I think that I would go with jdavies answer which seems pretty good.